# How to link bootstrap files with jsp file

Tags: java, twitter-bootstrap, jsp

Okay, I'm new to JSP and I'm trying to create a simple form with button in a JSP file `index.jsp` and link it to bootstrap. I just can't figure out how to call the bootstrap files from JSP. Here is my JSP code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <link href=”Bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css” rel=”stylesheet” type=”text/css” />
        <script type=”text/javascript” src=”Bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js”></script>
        <title>Bootstrap Project</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class=”container”>
            <form role=”form”>
                <div class=”form-group”>
                    <label for=”exampleInputEmail1″>Email address</label>
                    <input type=”email” class=”form-control” id=”exampleInputEmail1″ placeholder=”Enter email”>
                </div>
                <div class=”form-group”>
                    <label for=”exampleInputPassword1″>Password</label>
                    <input type=”password” class=”form-control” id=”exampleInputPassword1″ placeholder=”Password”>
                </div>
                <div class=”form-group”>
                    <label for=”exampleInputFile”>File input</label>
                    <input type=”file” id=”exampleInputFile”>
                    <p class=”help-block”>Example block-level help text here.</p>
                </div>
                <div class=”checkbox”>
                    <label>
                        <input type=”checkbox”> Check me out
                    </label>
                </div>
                <button type=”submit” class=”btn btn-default”>Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is my folder arrangement:
[image: Project Folders]

I'm using `Eclipse` IDE and `Tomcat` as the server. Where am I going wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: What problem are you having? Using bootstrap with a JSP file shouldn't be any different than using it with an HTML file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Okay when I deploy and run the above, it displays plain html form & button. It seems I'm importing the css & js scripts wrong. Any clue where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Most of the double quotes in the code you posted are not actual double quotes, but smart quotes. I'd start by fixing the HTML. The paths to the CSS seem correct (provided the files are indeed named that way and located under Bootstrap/css and Bootstrat/js, which you haven't shown. You should also learn to indent your code. It's unreadable that way.

Comment: Thank you JB Nizet. I hadn't noticed the quotes, funnily, in eclipse they are okay I guess when I copied them here they changed or something (that sounds impossible though).  The locations are correct but the problem still persists.

Comment: Thanks guys, I managed to fix it after changing the quotes. I appreciate!

Comment: code alignment and grammar corrections